# Twitter as Auth system in Silex

Tags: php, security, twitter, authorization, silex

In my project I'm using Twitter as user data provider.

I found this code: https://gist.github.com/adeslade/1148079
and I'm using it with this custom middleware

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

$app['controllers']
    -> before(function ($request) use ($app) {

        $path = substr($request -> getRequestUri(), strlen($request -> getBasePath()));

        // I put all twitter data in the session under the key "twitter"
        if (!$app['session'] -> has('twitter'))
            if (!preg_match("#^(/|/login(/.*)?)$#", $path))
                return new RedirectResponse('/');
    });
```

This works fine, but my hope is to use the preinstalled tool [SecurityServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html) like [GromNaN/FacebookServiceProvider](https://github.com/GromNaN/FacebookServiceProvider) and [sensiolabs/Silex-Connect](https://github.com/sensiolabs/Silex-Connect) **without** lose days creating it.

Is it recommended to follow my intention or could it become a second big project?

Comment: There are a few Oauth providers you could use for Twitter access see: https://github.com/benja-M-1/OAuthSecurityServiceProvider

Comment: tryed but it doesn't work with the Twitter authentication system, only old OAuth and Github